# Parsley v2.0.0-rc2 prevent disabled fields validation

Tags: jquery, validation, parsley.js

How to prevent Parsley v2.0.0-rc2 from validating disabled fields? In previous version disabled fields were ignored by default.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can avoid parsley validation by typing this in the form element:

```
data-parsley-excluded="[disabled=disabled]"
```

You can set any type of jquery selector to exclude from validation.

Comment: i like it when they add new features to a lib that are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-usage-field

You should look at the parsley documentation and use groups. You can set certain fields to be validated and submitted so that you don't have to validate everything, such as login section of a form that is also a part of a signup form.

Comment: Not sure is that optimal solution since i have only one field in form and it should be validated only if enabled.

Comment: you essentially would be activating the group to be validated when the field is enabled.

Comment: Another solution is to add/remove data-parsley-... attribute when field is enabled/disabled.

Comment: Well did this help you at all?

Comment: Yes it helped. Thanks :)
Even though I don't understand why there is no option to ignore disabled or hidden fields by default.